# Checking if a set participants already exists in a Threaded Database schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, design-patterns, database-design, messaging

I am creating a threaded messaging system for a web application, much like in Facebook's messaging system. I followed the other database schemes for threaded messages here in StackOverflow, but I haven't seen my requirement in theirs.

So I have three tables:

```
Conversations
    - conversationId

Messages:
   - messageId
   - conversationId
   - body

Participants
   - conversationId
   - userId
```

If a user creates a new conversation, a new conversation record is created in the `Conversations` table. The body of the message, along with subsequent replies, are stored in the `Messages` table with the conversationId. Finally, the participants, both the sender and 1 or more receivers, are added to the `Participants` table.

For example, person A sends person B a message. If the conversation between A and B does not exist yet, it should create a new conversation with a new ID. But if A and B already has a record, it should just add the message to the `Messages` table with the existing conversation ID. If A sends B and C, that's a new thread and should not be included with the last conversation.

If the user creates a new conversation to someone he already had conversation with (person A and B already had an existing conversation), the messaging app should not create another conversation Id but just get the conversationId with all the participants existing.

What I want to know is how to find out which conversation I should append the new message to. How should I formulate my query to get the conversation Id with the exact participants? If the participant userIds do not match, it should return 0. Is there a better database scheme to suit my requirement?

Answer (score 0):

The following query will tell you all conversations that have a given set of users (encoded as separate variables):

```
select conversation_id
from Participants p
group by conversation_id
having sum(case when user_id = @User1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when user_id = @User2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       . . .
       sum(case when user_id not in (@user1, @user2, . . .) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

The first clauses check that all the users are on the conversation.  That last checks that they are the only ones.  If you want to return `0` instead of no rows, you can do this with aggregation:

```
select coalesce(max(conversation_id), 0)
from Participants p
group by conversation_id
having sum(case when user_id = @User1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when user_id = @User2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       . . .
       sum(case when user_id not in (@user1, @user2, . . .) then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, it seems that in your solution you have to know the number of users in advance since you have to place them in a variable. Also the number of `having` statements depend on the number of users. Is there any way to make it dynamic, that is should be applicable if there are only 1 recipient or even 20?